# How can I get a count of all documents in all site collections?

Tags: document-library, site-collection

And if I need to make the same count but with some field filters?

Is the best approach populate a list using SPSiteDataQuery and then make the report from that  same list?

spregards

Comment: Do you have to do it once or many times? if it's once, a simple recursive powershell script can do the job.

Comment: I want to have it always displayed and reported. I try via Report Builder but that way comes up to be restrictive in terms of filtering by content types fields. Now I'm inclined to populate a list using SPSiteDataQuery and then make the report from that list.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're talking about using the Object Model, then I'd recommend [SPSiteDataQuery](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spsitedataquery.aspx).

It has many options for filtering the results, including by list template (e.g. document library).